Fallo de instalacion de parrot os , me sale esta pantalla
cuando voy a instalar parrot os desde un pen booteable al arrancar me muestra el siguiente mensaje , alguien sabe que es lo que esta fallando?
GNU GRUB version 2.06-13+parrot5
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. for the first word , TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device os file completion
grub>
(al pulsar TAB las me dice lo siguiente)
aunthenticate boot break clear configfile continue export extract_entries:configfile extract_entries_source gettext insmod is menuentry net_add_addr net_add_dns net_add_route net_bootp net_bootp6 net_del_addr net_del_dns net_del.....
les agradeceria mucho cualquier ayuda , un saludo , trate de subir captura pero no me deja y bajando la resolucion de la imagen tampoco.
